# Powerpoint deskop only requirements

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

Developing an add-in for PowerPoint. The features of the add-in are only supported by the desktop and tablet versions of the software. Any suggestions for targeting these platforms? Should we check for feature and display some type of Unsupported message for web users?

Answer (score 0):

This is the scenario that Requirement Sets were created for. Please see the official documentation:

[Office versions and requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-versions-and-requirement-sets)

[Specify Office hosts and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements)

[Office Add-in Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets)

[PowerPoint API Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/powerpoint-api-requirement-sets)

Comment: Thanks, however I don't see how to exclude the WEB client they all use the same PowerPointApi 1.1. Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/powerpoint-api-requirement-sets

Comment: What is not supported on the web?